# how do i move a piece of text & an image up/down the screen whilst keeping them aligned side by side?

Tags: javascript, html, css, encoding

I've just started coding less than 7 hours ago. I have all the basics and some more to memory but this I can't find a solution for anywhere.

Here is the dummy html file containing just text & image I'm using until I get it right;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <p><img src="https://images-eu.ssl-images- 
amazon.com/images/I/71VQR1WetdL.png" 
style="float:left;width:60px;height:60px;"><i><b><font size='10'><font 
color='red'><font face="calibri">@17thursday</font></b></i>
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body></p>

  </body>

</html>
```

You will notice both image & text should be aligned side by side at the top of the screen. It's getting them both to the bottom of the screen I'm struggling with.

Comment: you need to move the code below `<head>` and above `<title>` to body instead first of all

Comment: Also here's a link to help you get better understanding html with examples https://learn.freecodecamp.org/responsive-web-design/basic-html-and-html5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <p><img src="https://images-eu.ssl-images- 
amazon.com/images/I/71VQR1WetdL.png" 
style="float:left;width:60px;height:60px;position:fixed;bottom:0px;"><i><b><font size='10'><font 
color='red'><font face="calibri">@17thursday</font></b></i></p>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you, however upon trying this, the text&image stays at the top of the page?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put your design code's in "head" tag!

You should define them in "body" tag